# Как загрузить массив картинок из интернета в фоновом потоке на внутреннюю память на Андроид?

Tags: android, java, android-asynctask

Всем добрый день!
Пытаюсь реализовать следующую задачу:
Имеется JSON файл, при парсинге которого я получаю ссылки на png картинки. Все это происходит в фоновом потоке, и мне нужно в этот же фоновый поток засунуть функцию сохранения этих картинок по URL на внутреннюю память Android устройства(в кэш).
Так Вот посмотрел кучу разных примеров, но ни один из них не смог нормально приспособить к моей программе! Как мне организовать процесс загрузки?
Заранее спсибо! Буду рад любой помощи!

Answer (score 1):

организовать вот так:

[Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

Comment: Я знаю эту библиотеку, знаю как с ее помощью получать картинки по URL! А как сохранить? Если все просто подскажи как!

Comment: документацию к библиотеке разве нельзя прочитать?
автор постарался и даже на гитхабе страничку читабельно оформил....

.cacheInMemory()
.cacheOnDisc()

Comment: Я выставляю это в настройках и использую функцию loadImage и ни черта!